# Get time difference between CFAbsoluteTime and NSDate

Tags: ios, iphone, date, ios8

I have an CFAbsoluteTime and I need to get the time difference between the current time and return it as a CFAbsoluteTime. Is there a way to do this that does not include me doing all the conversions as a NSDate?

Answer (score 2):

A time difference is represented by `CFTimeInterval`, not `CFAbsoluteTime`, but anyway they are in fact both type aliases for `double`.  So get the `CFAbsoluteTime` of the `NSDate` and subtract:

```
CFTimeInterval difference = someAbsoluteTime - myDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate;
```